# Unsure about DatePicker data type format

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

i'm new to using C# and .NET and SQL Server...i'm doing a form design to allow a staff member to register a customer's details to a database. in the form i have the method to extract the data from the fields in the form, as well as a date picker to enter a customer's date of birth, however i am finding a bit of trouble to enter the format and default data type as i am unsure of how i am to go about doing this...the code for my form is shown below..."dobTP" is the name of my date picker box:

```
        SAF.AddNewCustomer(CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, CustomerContactNumber, dobTP, CustomerUsername, CustomerPassword, CustomerAddress, CustomerLicense, CustomerCreditCard);
        txtCustomerFirst.Text = "";
        txtCustomerLast.Text = "";
        txtCustomerContact.Text = "";
        dobTP ??
        txtCustomerUsername.Text = "";
        txtCustomerPassword.Text = "";
        txtCustomerAddress.Text = "";
        txtCustomerLicense.Text = "";
        txtCustomerCredit.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Created");
```

Comment: Are you using asp.net or asp.net mvc or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which DatePicker control are you using?

It's been my experience, most support a property, probably called SelectedDate that is of nullable **DateTime?** type. By setting this value to null, it will reset the DatePicker.

If you want to reset the .NET DateTimePicker control, it's Value property is not nullable.  There is a workaround to clear it, although I've never tried it.  Here is a link showing the workaround:  http://dotnetref.blogspot.com/2009/03/setting-datetimepicker-to-blank-value.html.

Comment: This, or if he's using something like the `CalendarExtender` from the AjaxControlToolkit, he would set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` control.

Comment: the DateTimePicker is what i'm using